# Dictionary contains list adress instead of list values C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to make a program which haves a dictionary with words and their definitions separated by ':' and each word separated by '|' but for some reason when i print the Values of the dictionary i get System.Collection.Generic.List instead

Here is a possible input: "tackle: the equipment required for a task or sport | code: write code for a computer program | bit: a small piece, part, or quantity of something | tackle: make determined efforts to deal with a problem | bit: a short time or distance"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ex1_Dictionary
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Input = Console.ReadLine().Split(':', '|').ToArray();
            var Words = new List<string>();
            var Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.Length; i+=2)
            {
                string word = Input[i];
                string definition = Input[i + 1];
                word = word.TrimStart();
                definition = definition.TrimStart();
                Console.WriteLine(definition);
                if (Dict.ContainsKey(word) == false)
                {
                    Dict.Add(word, new List<string>());
                }
                Dict[word].Add(definition);
            }
            foreach (var item in Dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd actually expect the output to be a `KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>`, because that's what you get as `item` when you iterate through `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` like you do in the line

```
foreach(var item in Dict)
```

You should change the output to something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ": " + string.Join(", " item.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to use `item.Value` instead of `item` to access your list of definitions.

You need to iterate through the definitions stored in your `List<string>`:

```
foreach (var item in Dict)
{
    foreach (var definition in item.Value) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(definition);
    }
}
```

This will print a line for every definition in your lists. If you want to print all definitions in a single line, you can do the following instead:

```
foreach (var item in Dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not split("|"). Then, foreach, split(":")?